# How to adjust the UTC format on a X axis of shield UI Chart

Tags: shieldui

I am using Shield UI Chart and have a datetime X axis, which I declare so:

```
axisX: {
     axisType: 'datetime'
},
```

I am not quite sure about the values of dataStart, where in the documentation I see:

```
dataStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0,1),
```

Why is there a 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month and days arrays in the dataStart collection start (as do arrays mostly do) from 0 and not from 1. Therefore January 1-st 2010 will be

```
dataStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0,1),
```

We have the following format:

```
dataStart: Date.UTC(YYYY, M, D),
```